# When reversing a Google Analytics e-commerce transaction is the per-unit price positive or negative?

Tags: google, google-analytics, analytics

Google's own [instructions for reversing an e-commerce transaction](http://support.google.com/analytics/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=1037443) seem to contradict themselves regarding the unit price.

In the instructions it states

> The item field has a positive per-unit price and a negative quantity.

yet, the code sample has a negative per-unit price and negative quantity.

```
_gaq.push(['_addItem',
       '1234',           // order ID - necessary to associate item with transaction
       'DD44',           // SKU/code - required
       'T-Shirt',        // product name
       'Olive Medium',   // category or variation
       '-11.99',          // unit price - required
       '-1'               // quantity - required
    ]);
```

Which is correct?

Answer (score 3):

After experimenting on a test account it seems the instructions are correct and the example isn't or rather, may not be. (I did not test the opposite case). I tested with the unit price being positive and the quantity negative as in the example below. Analytics reported the transaction but the total amount purchased was $0.

```
_gaq.push(['_addItem',
       '1234',           // order ID - necessary to associate item with transaction
       'DD44',           // SKU/code - required
       'T-Shirt',        // product name
       'Olive Medium',   // category or variation
       '11.99',          // unit price - required
       '-1'               // quantity - required
    ]);
```