# Google reverse an analytic

Tags: google-analytics

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [When reversing a Google Analytics e-commerce transaction is the per-unit price positive or negative?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/29448/when-reversing-a-google-analytics-e-commerce-transaction-is-the-per-unit-price-p)

I am confused about what code must be executed to reverse a google analytic.  I have the following code pasted within a test page:

```
<body onLoad=”function()”>
<script type="text/javascript">
  var _gaq = _gaq || [];
  _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-25305776-3']);
  _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);

    _gaq.push(['_addTrans',
       '11455',           // order ID - required
       '-42.38',          // total - required
       '-2.38',           // tax
       '-15.00'          // shipping
    ]);
    _gaq.push(['_addItem',
       '11455',           // order ID - necessary to associate item with transaction
       'Evan Turner Turningpoint™ Basketball Pants',        // product name
       '25.00',          // unit price - required
       '-1'               // quantity - required
    ]);
    _gaq.push(['_trackTrans']);

  (function() {
    var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
    ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
  })();
  </script>
```

Is this correct?  Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean "reverse an analytic"?

Comment: Hi, This code was copied from http://support.google.com/analytics/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=1037443 in an attempt to reverse a google analytics entry. Thanks!

Comment: am not understanding this question..you want to reverse an e-commerce transaction?

Comment: Yes, I want to reverse an e-commerce transaction.

Answer (score 1):

Using the link provided by Dan, http://support.google.com/analytics/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=1037443, the title of the question should probably "How to reverse an e-commerce transaction in google analytics"

For example someone cancels an order, this would capture that so google analytics has correct information.

Looking at the code, one thing is missing from "_gaq.push(['_addItem',"
The minus sign in '25.00', so it should be:

```
_gaq.push(['_addItem',
   '11455',           // order ID - necessary to associate item with transaction
   'Evan Turner Turningpoint™ Basketball Pants',        // product name
   '-25.00',          // unit price - required
   '-1'               // quantity - required
]);
```

Comment: Hi Thank you for your answer.  Unfortunately, I have tried the code with both positive and negative 25 and the record still persists in GA.

Comment: If you have tried both the positive and the negative would they not effectively cancel each other out in the transaction total? Also, did you read from the link you supplied: "Reversing a transaction does not remove it. Both the original transaction and the reversal transaction are included in the transaction count."

Comment: I did read the post I provided but missed any reference to both orig and rev trans remaining in the trans count.